# Access collection of user setting current values

Tags: vb.net

Is there a built in collection of the current values of user settings that is accessible? Using the loop below, I can iterate through the default user settings however, I cannot access their current values. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
For Each setting As System.Configuration.SettingsProperty In My.Settings.Properties
    Console.WriteLine(setting.Name & " >> " & setting.DefaultValue)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The `My.Settings` property will give you access to a given applications users settings so you are looking at the right thing.  These can be arbitrarily written and stored with the `Save` method.  Once you call `Save` the values should persist across instances of the application.

Note though that this only applies to your application, not others.  To have settings across applications you will need to choose a different storage medium like the registry

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am familiar in the general use of My.Settings. In this case, I looking to access the names and values of the My.Settings properties without explicitly specifying the name of each property. Ultimately, I need to roll them up into a json object to be passed in an ajax call from another app. I was hoping that I could accomplish this without having to access the xml file directly or explicitly referencing each My.Settings property.